# Unity: Why does Addressable detect prefab changes when I only changed the attached monoscript?

Tags: unity-game-engine, addressables

Addressable detected prefab changes when I only changed the attached monoscript

For example: I have a monoscript attached on LevelView prefab. whenever I change this monoscript(for example: add a line) then run the "Check for Content Update Restrictions" it shows LevelView prefab has been changed.

For other prefabs, it gives the same result.

There is no change of this prefab, form source control.

I dont want this happen. Is it a bug? Im using addressables 1.20.5 Unity 2020.3.36

[image]

---

Last night, I had read the source code of addressable, I found out that addressable would add warning flag if any dependency of this asset had changed.

In my case, the monoscript is the prefab's dependency. So when i change the monoscript, the prefab is flagged.

I dont know why does addressables design like this? And there is no optional case for user to choose.

Comment: Can you give an example of the type of line you add to the code?  Are there serialized fields (which causes the component to see changes in its corresponding save file), or are the changes to logic which would not alter the save file?  Do you see changes in your source control to the referenced prefab(s)?

Comment: There is no change of this prefab, form source control. I had read the source code of addressable, I found out that addressable would add warning flag if any dependency of this asset had changed.

In my case, the monoscript is the prefab's dependency. So when i change the monoscript, the prefab is flagged.

I dont know why does addressable design like this? And there is no optional case for user to choose.